# Flink Parallelism with event time window

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm reading from Kafka from a topic with partition = 1, using Windows Event Time without a key. As a result, this code did not close (output) the results of the window. I twisted and figured it out for a long time. As a result, I added `env.setParallelism(1);` and suddenly everything worked.

I want to understand why this parameter is needed in my example? Why didn't the windows close in my example without this parameter?

1. Also in the documentation I found that windows without keys always have a concurrency of 1.
2. I also want to add that with `TumblingProcessingTimeWindows`, everything **works perfectly** regardless of the parameter `env.setParallelism(1);`

- 

```
   StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
            env.setParallelism(1);
            KafkaSource<UserModel> source = KafkaSource.<UserModel>builder().setBootstrapServers(kafka).setTopics("f1").setGroupId("flink_group").setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
                    .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new JsonConverter()).build();
    
            DataStream<UserModel> ds = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka Source");
    
     WatermarkStrategy<UserModel> strategy = WatermarkStrategy.<UserModel>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
                    .withTimestampAssigner((i, timestamp) -> {
                        return i.dt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli();
                    });
    
            SingleOutputStreamOperator<UserModelEx> reduce = ds.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(strategy)
                    .windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10)))
                    .reduce((acc, i) -> {
                        acc.count += i.count;
                        acc.dt = i.dt;
                        System.out.println(acc.dt + " reduce:" + acc.count);
                        return acc;
                    }, new Rich());
    
    
            reduce.print();
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a reason why changing the parallelism would cause your window trigger to start working. I'm guessing it's some other issue with your code.

But in looking at your code, this line isn't good:

```
DataStream<UserModel> ds = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka Source");
```

Instead of passing in the `noWatermarks()` strategy you should be providing the `strategy` you define just after that line.

Also the `acc.dt = i.dt` line is only valid if you have a single input partition to your reduce, and you know that events in the Kafka topic are ordered by time:

```
                    .reduce((acc, i) -> {
                        acc.count += i.count;
                        acc.dt = i.dt;
                        System.out.println(acc.dt + " reduce:" + acc.count);
                        return acc;
```

Otherwise you're setting the accumulator time based on some random element in your window.

But if that's true, then you can and should use the built-in `forMonotonousTimestamps` watermark strategy (instead of `forBoundedOutOfOrderness`), which will give you the most accurate watermark with no latency.